# Finding a limit of a quotient with trig

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm studying for my Cal 2 exam, but I can't remember how to do the following question:

Find the limit, as n approaches infinity, of the sequence or prove that the limit does not exist:
$$\lim_{n \to {\infty}}{{3 \cdot n^2 \cdot \cos(n \cdot \pi)} \over {\sqrt{1+4 \cdot n^4}}}$$

Please guide me in the right path. Thanks!

Comment: What is your limit approaching? You might want to add that in.

Comment: It doesn't say, but I'm assuminf Infinity

Comment: where is $x$ in your formula?

Comment: It's a sequence. n is approaching Infinity. There aren't any x's

Comment: @AftabHussain I made another edit, tell me if that looks right.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the edits Zach and Danimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract $2n^2$ from the denominator:

$$\lim_{n \to {\infty}}{{3 n^2 \cdot \cos(n \pi)} \over 2n^2 {\sqrt{\frac{1}{4n^4}+1}}}$$

Simplify the fraction:

$$\lim_{n \to {\infty}}{{3 \cdot \cos(n \pi)} \over 2 {\sqrt{\frac{1}{4n^4}+1}}}$$

As $n \to \infty$, we can see that $\frac{1}{4n^4} \to 0$, so that $\sqrt{\frac{1}{4n^4} + 1} \to \sqrt{0 + 1} = 1$, so the limit equals:

$$\lim_{n \to {\infty}}{\frac{3}{2} \cos(n \pi)}$$

Which does not exist, as the values for $\cos(n\pi)$ keep fluctuating between $1$ and $-1$ as  you increment $n$, so the sequence will tend to $\frac{-3}{2}, \frac 32, \frac{-3}{2}, \frac 32, \dots$

Comment: tl;dr version: the "dominant powers" of numerator and denominator are the same, so they balance each other. But the remaining term oscillates, so the limit doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

$$(1) \quad \lim_{n \to {\infty}}{{3 \cdot n^2 \cdot \cos(n \cdot \pi)} \over {\sqrt{1+4 \cdot n^4}}}$$

This limit is undefined...

**Proof:**

Let's divide both the numerator and denominator by $n^2$ we'll get...

$$(2) \quad \lim_{n \to {\infty}}{{3 \cdot \cos(n \cdot \pi)} \over {\sqrt{1/n^4+4}}}$$

Apply the quotient rule...

$$(3) \quad {\lim_{n \to {\infty}}{3 \cdot \cos(n \cdot \pi)} \over {\lim_{n \to {\infty}}\sqrt{1/n^4+4}}}$$

Ok, the denominator clearly goes to $4$, but the numerator is indeterminate. Keep in mind that cosine is periodic, but since we approach infinity, we can't define its value. The most we can say is that it's between $-1$ and $1$.

Thus, the limit is undefined.

Comment: The final bit about $\cos$ is slightly inaccurate: what if the expression had been $\cos\left(n\pi + \frac{\pi (n+1)}{2n}\right)$? (Note that this is a sequence $\Bbb N \to \Bbb R$, not a function $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.)

Comment: @Mauris But it's *not* that expression. It's just a vanilla cosine ;)

Comment: Agree -- that's why I said "slightly"! What I'm a bit worried about is this: *"(something) is periodic, but since we approach infinity, we can't define its value"* is reasoning that applies here, but it *sounds* a lot like it might generalize, while there are certainly cases where it doesn't apply (see my example.)

Comment: @Mauris well, now they have your post to warn them :)